# Нужно узнать длину массива строк

Tags: c++

Имеется тип `string` из `std`, нужно узнать длину массива этого типа.

```
std::string arrayT [] = {"value1", "value2", "value3"};
std::cout << sizeof (arrayT) << std::endl;
```

Всегда возвращает 8, независимо от кол-ва ключей/значений.

Есть другие варианты?

Оригинальный код:

```
string arrayT [] = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6"};
json.setString (arrayT, "testValue");

void JSON::setString (string key [], string value)
{
  std::wcout << sizeof (key) << std::endl;
}
```

> > Вывод: 8

Comment: https://ideone.com/4II92Y - вполне себе 96, а не 8. Не надо тут не тот код показывать.

Comment: Наверное в оригинале указатель, а не массив со скобками

Comment: Добавил оригинальный код

Comment: Вам 2 раза ответили **как** считать **длину** массива, а вы снова пытаетесь узнать его **размер**. 8 - это размер указателя на 64-разрядной машине, а в вашем примере нет ни одного указателя.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, ну так я-то догадался :)

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, уже есть - во втором коде `key`.

Comment: @Qwertiy поспешил.

Answer (score 5):

Совершенно не важно какого типа у вас массив. Для выяснения количества элементов любого массива достаточно поделить общий размер массива в байтах на размер отдельного элемента:

```
sizeof(array) / sizeof(element);
```

Чтобы явно не указывать в этом выражении тип элемента можно использовать либо оператор разыменования `*`, или указать элемент по индексу (обычно используют `0`):

```
sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

Видно, что вариант с разыменованием самый лаконичный.

Чтобы, тем не менее, не повторять это деление компилятор от Microsoft предоставляет для этих целей макрос [`_countof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175773.aspx):

```
_countof(array);
```

Если не хочется использовать макросы (а их лучше НЕ использовать, если есть такая возможность), то можно написать шаблонную функцию, принимающую ссылку на массив:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t countof(T const (&)[N]) noexcept
{
    return N;
}
```

В с++17 для этих целей появилась функция [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size):

```
std::size(array);
```

---

Проблема с выводом `8` в коде заключается в том, что при передаче в функцию массив вырождается в указатель и таким образом `sizeof` даёт размер указателя. Именно поэтому часто приходится наблюдать передачу пары аргументов - указатель и размер данных по этому указателю.

Хотите иметь возможность сохранять размер - используйте `std::array` или `std::vector` при передаче в функцию. Тогда всегда сможете вызвать для них функцию-член `size` или упомянутую выше `std::size`, если компилятор позволяет.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof - это унарный оператор, возвращающий длину в байтах переменной или типа, помещенных в скобки.
Можно сделать так:

```
std::string arrayT [] = {"value1", "value2", "value3"};
std::cout << (sizeof(arrayT)/sizeof(*arrayT)) << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Разделите размер массива на размер `std::string` и узнаете длину массива.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string arrayT [] = {"value1", "value2", "value3"};
  size_t arrSize = sizeof(arrayT) / sizeof(std::string);
  std::cout << arrSize << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: sizeof (std::string) - выводит 40, а sizeof (arrayT) - 8. Получается всегда 0

Comment: @АнтонСеров  а у меня получилось 3.